# Reserved words in NHibernate

Tags: oracle, nhibernate

I need to reference a column called limit in a legacy oracle database and also use a SQLite in-memory database for unit testing.
I have read to use backticks in the mapping files to accomplish this; `limit` which works fine in SQLite, but resolves to "limit" in oracle and barfs on the query.

Is this feature implemented correctly for oracle or am I missing something?

Cheers,

Rob

UPDATE

It seems the column wasn't created with quotes around it, but NHibernate recognises it as reserved and puts quotes round it :/

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle you use double-quotes to reference objects with names as reserved words:

```
SQL> create table a (number number);

create table a (number number)
                ^
ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
```

"NUMBER" is a reserved word. However, you can:

```
SQL> create table a ("number" number);

Table created

SQL> select "number" from a;

    number
----------
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, thats exactly how it is resolved in the query:
SELECT payment."limit" as limit7_8_0_ from payment

which throws ORA-00904: "limit": invalid identifier :/